# Linq to entities(latest entity framework) get many to many and one to many relation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

i have a **quotation** table with quotationid , QuotationNo

i have a **berth** with berthid and berthname

i have a third table **quotationberth** with quotationid and berthid

i have a viewmodel

```
public class QuotationViewModel
{      
    public int QuotationId { get; set;}
    public string QuotationNo { get; set; }     
    public List<quotationberth> quoationbirth{ get; set; }      
}
```

how can i get this viewmodel? what is the most appropiate way? is this the appropiate way to query

```
from quot in _context.Quotations
 select new QuotationViewModel
                {
                    QuotationId = quot.QuotationId,
                    QuotationNo = quot.QuotationNo,
                    quoationbirth=quot.QuotationBerth. (what comes here)

                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Firstly why Id's and No's and then a list of the Id's and No's ? Nothing goes there as you are populating a list eh ? is quot.QuotationBirth a list? P.S. To get from one side of a many to many to the other you would typically do a left outer join i believe.

Comment: I think it should be "quoationbirth=quot.QuotationBerth.ToList()" if it's IQuaryable<QuotationBerth> Can you write your Database Design Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your spelling of the property and type names is a bit inconsistent, and you didn't include your `Quotation` entity code, but if I assume the name of the child collection in `Quotation`:

```
from quot in _context.Quotations
select new QuotationViewModel
            {
                QuotationId = quot.QuotationId,
                QuotationNo = quot.QuotationNo,
                quoationbirth=quot.QuotationBerths
            }).ToList();
```

I'm making the assumption that `QuotationBerths` is the name of the collection of `quotationberth` entities inside the `Quotation` entity.